# OracleBulkCopy AutoCommits

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net, sqlbulkcopy

C#.Net I am using OracleBulkCopy to copy data to global temp tables that are declared as Delete on commit. So when I use OracleBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataReader). It commits and I am losing all the data. How to prevent this?

Comment: can you tell, why you are using a global temporary table at all and not a regular table?

Comment: @bernd_k because existing applications all work the same way. Copy data from source to temp table and run the stored procedure to move data from temp table to permanent. This is done using middle-tier where multiple threads access the global temp table simultaneously hence the delete on commit is used so that no 2 sessions share the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OracleBulkCopy seems not to support transactions. Auto commit is never smart to use, copy in a more controlled way for example using bulk inserts.

```
OPEN z;
LOOP
    FETCH z BULK COLLECT INTO z_array LIMIT z_array_size;

    FORALL i IN 1..z_array.COUNT
    INSERT INTO t2 VALUES z_array(i);

    EXIT WHEN z%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: you mean to say generate dynamic insert statement. We already using this, just wanted to try OracleBulkCopy as I thought it might be faster.

Comment: Yes, but use the bulk insert as shown. OracleBulkCopy could be a little faster, maybe, maybe not. I am not sure. Bulk inserts perform very well.

Answer (score 0):

It is no good idea to declare global temporary tables as Delete on commit when using .NET anyway.

Better practice is to delete from gtt before doing whatever you want and let it as it is after commit. Debugging becomes easier too.

Comment: @bernd_K: performance wise the worst thing to do is do a delete from such a table. Just forget about the data and have it cleaned up by the commit. In that case, the data just 'evaporates' on a very efficient way.

Comment: @bernd_K: There is a problem if we don't use delete on commit as multiple threads access the same global temp table simultaneously.

Comment: @bernd_k: no they use different oracle sessions

Comment: but when they use different sessions they don't see each others data even when using on commit preserve rows.

Comment: @bernd_k we did a small test, other sessions see the data.

Comment: Your sessions seem to reuse the same Oracle Session. Different Oracle sessions can't see each others data in the global temporary table.

Comment: @bernd_k I am not sure, but I guess what you said is correct.